# Will a 5v radio be safe to power with a PC PSU?

Tags: power-supply

I pulled a working PSU from a dead PC, and will I risk burning something with this circuit? WIll it cause a fire?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fefmKv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: `Will it cause a fire?` is a question that asks a 100% certainty about the fire ... such a question can never have a `yes` answer, because future cannot be predicted ... it's like asking `will I get sick tomorrow?` ... it could possibly cause a fire because the power supply is designed to supply a lot of current without shutting down ... the radio could fail in a way that would cause the radio to overheat

Comment: What radio is it, and how much it needs current? Most likely, a PC power supply is a poor general purpose power supply when you only load a single output rail. And yes, like any electronic device, the power supply may reach its end at any moment, and burn up and start a fire, even if you did not connect your radio to it. If the power supply is old, it might have failing capacitors and it could have problems with voltage ripple or keeping voltages in regulation.

Answer (score 1):

If the PSU is in a good condition, nothing bad should happen. However, you can put a fuse (check the current rating) between the PSU and the radio. That way, the fuse will blow in case of overcurrent, not giving enough time for the radio to be damaged.

On the side of the PSU external power (I assume a wall outlet), you may also try a fused connection (there are fused plugs and extensions you can use).

Comment: I would definitely suggest a fuse on the 5V wire. The average PC supply can pump out in excess of 20A that can melt wires and cause a fire. A 5V phone charger might be a much safer option.

Comment: Agree with the fuse recommendation.  Have seen a lab damaged by a fire caused from a shorted 1000w ATX power supply.  Without a fuse a short can very quickly cause a lot of damage with such supplies.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standby 5V line "5VSB", you don't need to power-on the main part of the PSU then.

Answer (score 0):

Safe, but probably useless.

ATX PSUs aren't designed for particularly low noise, so chances are it'll wipe out most of the AM band and probably the FM band too. If you can hear anything other than loud buzzing noises, go for it.